# Java Pattern issue

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am getting a text from the DB which contains Strings of the form

```
CO<sub>2</sub>
```

In order to recognize this I wrote the following code

```
String footText = "... some text containing CO<sub>2</sub>";
String co2HTML = "CO<sub>2</sub>";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(co2HTML);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(footText);

final boolean hasCO2 = mat.matches();
```

The problem is that hasCO2 is always false although the inout text has that substring.
What is wrong hete?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `String.contains(CharSequence)`?

Comment: Well, in fact the code is more complex. I've posted the kern of the problem and not the whole code. I do need Patterns. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `find()` instead of `matches()`, since the latter tries to match the entire string against the pattern rather than perform a search.

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> - The `matches` method attempts to match the entire input sequence    against the pattern.
> - The `lookingAt` method attempts to match the input sequence, starting    at the beginning, against the pattern.
> - The `find` method scans the input sequence looking for the next    subsequence that matches the pattern.

Also, the pattern in question doesn't really require regular expressions; you could use [`String.indexOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to perform the search.